# Unable to delete row in interactive report using ORACLE APEX

Tags: oracle-apex

I am unable to delete any row in my interactive report.
Steps: Create new interactive report page.

Create page item P400_EMPLOYEE_ID referring to PK employee_id and set to hidden.

For the virtual column 'del', properties are:
Type: link
URL: javascript:void(null);
Link Text: 
Link Attributes: data-id=#EMPLOYEE_ID#

Create Dynamic Action option: 
Name: DA_DELETEROW
Event: Click
Selection Type: jQuery Selector
jQuery Selector: .delete-irrow
Event Scope: Dynamic

right-click on the Dynamic Action DA_DELETEROW and select Create True Action :
Action: Confirm
Text: Are you sure to delete this employee?

2nd true action:
Action: Set Value
Set Type: JavaScript Expression
JavaScript Expression: $(this.triggeringElement).parent().data('id')
Selection Type: Item(s)
Item(s): P400_EMPLOYEE_ID
3rd true action:
Action: Execute PL/SQL Code
PL/SQL Code: Delete from employee_leave where employee_id= :P400_EMPLOYEE_ID;
Items to Submit: P400_EMPLOYEE_ID

Last true action set as refresh the region.

Despite this, i can see the delete button but unable to delete any row.
It just refreshes the page on delete and no row is deleted from report or table.

Please help!!!!!!

Comment: Add the 3rd action, `submit`?

Comment: details please???

Comment: You created a dynamic action with several "true" actions. So, add yet another which will submit that delete. Or, try with `commit;` at the end of the 2nd true action (after `delete from employee ...`).

Comment: oh, you mean item to submit? yes its blank.

Comment: no it worked, in pl/sql code, i did not add item to submit which would be :P400_EMPLOYEE_ID. It worked after it! :)

Comment: Aha. OK then, I'm glad you fixed it.

Comment: For posterity, I cover the concepts involved in this presentation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oidvwj38EBc&list=PLPIzp-E1msrblCGG4bOcg1wnNHj2QnIqZ&index=15&t=38m28s I touch on how you can debug part of it too.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to remove a row from the Interactive Grid using dynamic actions?  Wouldn't it be simpler to delete the row from the database and refresh the Interactive Report?